# Problem multiplying vec3 by model matrice (scaling problem)

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

in my 3D application I have an Object3D class which construct is bounding box at creation, this bounding box is a simple cuboid with a min and a max point : [image: simple cuboid bounding box]

However, when I translate my Object3D, I want to update my bounding box using the Model matrix of my object :

```
     BoundingBox& TransformBy(const glm::mat4& modelMatrice){
        //extract position of my model matrix
        glm::vec3 pos( modelMatrice[3] );
        
        //extract scale of my model matrix
        glm::vec3 scale( glm::length(glm::vec3(modelMatrice[0])), glm::length(glm::vec3(modelMatrice[1])) , glm::length(glm::vec3(modelMatrice[2])));
        
        //Creating vec4 min/max from vec3
        glm::vec4 min_(min.x, min.y, min.z, 1.0f);
        glm::vec4 max_(max.x, max.y, max.z, 1.0f);
        
        //Inverting the matrice to multiply my vec4 with it in order to rotate my min max
        glm::mat4 inverse = glm::inverse(modelMatrice);
        min_ = min_ * inverse;
        max_ = max_ * inverse;
        
        //Scale my min_ max_
        min_ *= glm::vec4(scale,1.0f);
        max_ *= glm::vec4(scale,1.0f);
        
        //adding model matrice translation to min_ and max_
        min_ += glm::vec4(pos,0.0f);
        max_ += glm::vec4(pos,0.0f);
    
        //Redefining max and min
        max = glm::vec3( (min_.x > max_.x)? min_.x:max_.x, (min_.y > max_.y)? min_.y: max_.y, (min_.z > max_.z)? min_.z : max_.z);
        min = glm::vec3( (min_.x < max_.x)? min_.x:max_.x, (min_.y < max_.y)? min_.y: max_.y, (min_.z < max_.z)? min_.z : max_.z);
        return *this;
    }
```

Here is how I call my TransformBy function :

```
box.TransformBy(transform.GetModelMatrix());
```

For some reason, it make my min and max point rotating correctly it also translate it but my scaling is not correctly applied, making my bounding box having a bigger scale than my 3D object.

**Why my scaling is not working properly ?
Maybe there is a less complicated way of doing what I want ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly how the result of `GetModelMatrix()` is supposed to look, i.e. that it is just a normal 4x4 transformation matrix, then I think I can guess what the problem is. I find it easiest to visualize/explain with an example, so hopefully that's alright.

Suppose your result of `GetModelMatrix()` is the following, a simple transformation matrix with no rotational component, just a translation by [5 6 7].

```
| 1 0 0 5 |
| 0 1 0 6 |
| 0 0 1 7 |
| 0 0 0 1 |
```

The inverse of that, which gets passed in as `modelMatrice`, is just:

```
| 1 0 0 -5 |
| 0 1 0 -6 |
| 0 0 1 -7 |
| 0 0 0  1 |
```

After calling `glm::vec4 min_(min.x,min.y,min.z,1.0f);`, let us represent `min_` by the vector `[x y z 1]`. Then `min_ * modelMatrice` looks like:

```
            | 1 0 0 -5 |   
            | 0 1 0 -6 |
[x y z 1] * | 0 0 1 -7 | = [x y z (-5x-6y-7z+1)]
            | 0 0 0  1 |
```

That is, the x, y, and z components are not altered because it is the `|0 0 0 1|` row that gets applied to them in the multiplication, not the column containing the translation components.

May I ask, do you have a particular reason for (a) inverting `GetModelMatrix()` and (b) multiplying the matrix by the vector as opposed to vice versa? I'd guess that perhaps your code should instead look as follows:

```
BoundingBox& TransformBy(const glm::mat4 modelMatrice){
        ...
        min_ = modelMatrice * min_;
        max_ = modelMatrice * max_;
        ...
        return *this;
    }
```

Called with `box.TransformBy(transform.GetModelMatrix());`

**Update:**

In regards to your new code, I question the need for inversion of the transformation matrix for rotation, the need to split up the scaling/translation/rotation into three separate steps, etc. It feels like, unless there is an error somewhere else, the process should be as simple as taking your object's transformation vector, multiplying min_ and max_ by it, and then doing the test for whether any min/max components swapped that you currently have at the end of the function:

```
     BoundingBox& TransformBy(const glm::mat4& modelMatrice){
        min_ = modelMatrice * min_;
        max_ = modelMatrice * max_;
        max = glm::vec3( (min_.x > max_.x)? min_.x:max_.x, (min_.y > max_.y)? min_.y: max_.y, (min_.z > max_.z)? min_.z : max_.z);
        min = glm::vec3( (min_.x < max_.x)? min_.x:max_.x, (min_.y < max_.y)? min_.y: max_.y, (min_.z < max_.z)? min_.z : max_.z);
        return *this;
    }
```

If the above five-line function does not work, please let me know how it fails; if it does not work, I feel the problem may lie elsewhere in your code.

However, to answer your updated question, as to why the scaling does not work: When you invert the transformation matrix, you are also inverting the scaling. Thus, you are not just rotating when you multiply by `inverse`: you are also applying the inverted scale. While you could fix this by multiplying by the scale again, the far simpler solution seems to be trying to get the above five-line solution working.

Comment: Hello FilmCoder, thanks for your reply, My model matrix is a bit more complicated, it have transformation, Rotation and scaling. (a)(b) I'm inverting my model matrix to apply rotation to my min and max by mutiply them with matrice (it actually work) . I will edit my question with more data and the thing I have found

Comment: Hi Xemuth. I believe that the reason rotation works, in spite of the inversion, is because the inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose, and by switching the order of the vector and the matrix in your multiplication, you're effectively multiplying the vector by the transpose of the inverse of the rotation matrix, i.e. the inverse of the inverse, i.e. the original rotation matrix. A similar nice coincidence won't happen for translation, though. I imagine scaling might also be "inverted" if you test it out, i.e. your bounding box will shrink when your model grows.

Comment: I had try this thing ```min_ = modelMatrice * min_; max_ = modelMatrice * max_;``` without inverting my Model matrix but it don't work. I have found a way of making my translation occure (I have updated the question/post) . "I imagine scaling might also be "inverted"" Yes I think it's wrong that's why in my new function I only inverse my matrix when I need to rotate

Comment: How does having the program fail when you don't invert and have the multiplication the other way around? Does it simply not rotate at all, or is the rotation incorrect, or something else?

Comment: The rotation is incorrect. To verify my bounding box is rotating well, I print on screen a cube representing  the  center point of it, in parallel, my bounding box is printed on screen using a shader wich take my MVP matrix (the model of this MVP matrix is the same as in my function). To get the center point of my bounding box I do this : ```center = (min + max) * 0.5f ``` here you have the resullt of the same set of move with and without inversion : https://imgur.com/a/bShVKnS

Comment: If you want, I can provide some number ( min max value before rotation and after it)

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I'll give some thought as to what the problem might be. Is this obtained by taking your new code, where the scale/translation/rotation are all isolated and applied one-by-one, and simply not inverting the rotation matrix? If so, I can see why you might get the result you've screenshotted. Or is it closer to the five-line version I've updated my original answer with? Because then I think it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for the time you take to help me, both screenshot have been obtained by using my new code,  in one case I just don't inverse the matrix : ```min_ = modelMatrice * min_;  max_ = modelMatrice * max_ ; ``` also, in my new code, I don't invert the matrix when passing it to the function, I just do  box.TransformBy(transform.GetModelMatrix());

Comment: I havnt seen your update on your post, I'm giving a try to your 5 lines function.

Comment: Ok it  work perfectly, even the scale problem is solved. thanks for your help, that's really strange the things are that's simple  (I mean when I coded the function I don't get how I don't try first to multiply my vector by model, maybe I had multiply my vector with matrix instead of multiplying my matrix with vector)  well tanks again.

Comment: That's awesome! Very happy to hear that it works now! Glad that I could help!